# Why do matplotlib subplots start with 1

Tags: python, matplotlib

When creating subplots with matplotlib you need to start with `1`, while most other python things start with zero. So to create the very first subplot (top left)

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(3,4,1)
```

Where I would have expected `0` to be the first subplot

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(3,4,0)
```

I've seen the explanation "we got this from matlab" but that seems like a particularly unsatisfying answer.

Comment: Yet “we got this from matlab” is the answer!

Comment: I find myself using [`subplots`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots) more often.  It returns an array of `Axis` objects and you can index the array in the usual Python way.

Comment: I just found `plt.subplot2grid` also which is pythonic too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer really is: "it's meant for matlab-compatibility".  There is one minor advantage in terms of the shortcut integer notation (`subplot(231)` instead of `subplot(2,3,1)`).  You can't express a 0-based system that way without using strings instead.  However, that shortcut notation is generally a bad idea, and should only ever be used in an interactive scenario where readability isn't a concern.

As @Cong Ma mentioned, in most cases, you'd use `subplots` and index a 2D array instead of the matlab-style numerical system. It's a better approach all-around.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3)
axes[0, 0].plot(range(10))

plt.show()
```

It's not exactly identical, as it also adds all of the subplots, but you can always hide the ones you don't want to be visible (`ax.axis('off')` or `ax.set(visible=False)`).